# Using Image Detection to detect lines?

Tags: image, image-processing

I am trying to figure out how to use RANSAC for line detection, I am using canny edge detection to detect initial edges within the image, however would I randomly take a sample of the pixel values, or pixel locations from the image to model the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use locations of course. You cannot get a line from intensities.

Edge detectors usually generate two kinds of pixels. Non-edge pixels who are usually black and edge-pixels who are not black. Their values sometimes bear information on the edge quality.

Just pick a random set of edge-points...

Also there is plenty of literature online. Just google and read what you find.

http://cs.gmu.edu/~kosecka/cs682/lect-fitting.pdf for example...

Comment: Would it be a good idea after applying canny edge, to first cycle through the image and select record all edges where the pixel values are higher than 0 or some threshold, then select a random sample from the edge set collected?

Comment: yes usually you would create a list of 2d points to work with.

Comment: What I mean is would you avoid all the locations of black pixels and record the edge pixels which in this case are white?

Comment: @John321 yes you put the edge pixels into a list and work with that